# How to disable the auto-indentation of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, indentation

How can I disable the feature that when I hit "return" the cursor will be placed on the next line with tabs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Xcode - preference(or press keys command+,) - Indentations

There you can disable it.

Comment: In Xcode 5, the pref is now at **Preferences > *Text Editing* > Indentation (tab)**.

Comment: Xcode 11 is out, this answer is obsolete and needs editing

Answer (score 3):

For **Xcode 7** (and presumably from at least Xcode 5) you can turn off auto indentation from preferences. That is either hit <kbd>command+,</kbd> (i.e. comma), or *Xcode > Preferences...*, and then select *Text Editing > Indentations* where you can remove the tick in front of *Automatically indent based on syntax* close to the middle of page.

Answer (score 0):

Exact Steps For XCode 3.2.6:

XCode, Preferences, Indentation, "Syntax Aware Indenting" Section,

Under "Automatically indented characters", uncheck "Return"

Also, The [XCode User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/Xcode_User_Defaults.pdf) document from Apple (which may require a devloper login to view), provides much more fine grained control over the XCode IDE.

To set and then readback indivdual settings use something like:

```
defaults write com.apple.XCODE PBXIndentOnPaste No
defaults read com.apple.XCODE PBXIndentOnPast
```

Answer (score 0):

The XCode User Defaults document is obscolete for Xcode 6 --- at least none of the things that it documents seem to work any more. Also, there's no way to turn off auto indent (in the sense of matching the indent level of the previous line) from the Preferences menu. Disabling all options in that menu does not disable this behavior. Anybody have any how to actually solve this problem?